# Hide part of an image inside a div without class or id

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide part of an `image` wrapped inside a div without `clas`s or `id`. Since i'm parsing code from a rss feed i can not give class or id to the div (i mean i can do it manually but this means to lose the automated posting). The parent div has a `class` and then there are 3 other div-s without `class` or `id` and within the third div is the image.

```
<div class="post-body-container"><div><div><div><img src=""></img></div><p>text</p><p>text</p></div></div></div>
```

**What I have done till now:**

With this styling I can hide part of the image because i give overflow: hidden to the desired div. (:

```
<style>.post-body-container div div div {
width: 418px;
height: 200px; 
overflow: hidden;</style>
```

The problem is that even the other div-s receive the same styling (width and height).

**My question:**

How can I give styling ONLY to the div that wraps the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) if you want to you can add another class name to the div to select them specifically.

Comment: Hi. As i explained i'm posting automatically rss feed. If i give manually class to the div is not automatic posting anymore. I want to apply a general rule for all posts.

Comment: I think your code works well. 
Other divs don’t have any styling. (but it looks like they have height)

Comment: Yes they have height. You are right. That's what i'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: I don't know what do you want to. If child element has height, parent DIV also has height.

Comment: Hi @JohnGrischam, There is not a single selector available in `css`, that allows you to travel upside the `DOM`. You can do it using `javascript`.

Comment: I don't find this to be a duplicate of the parent selector question; OP is not trying to select a parent element, they are starting from the top of the tree.

Comment: @HamidR. They are not trying to navigate upside. They are starting from the top, and selecting descendant elements, see their code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) selector. ie `div > *` will target the first descendants of a node. If you chain them you will get the result you are looking for.

```
.post-body-container > div > div > div {
    width: 418px;
    height: 200px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you but  is not working since all div-s receive same styling.

Comment: Ooo actually you could use an `:nth-child()` selector which might just work. `.post-body-container > div:nth-child(3) > div > div`. Just replace the `3` with the index you need.